# C# IoC containers

Tags: c#, containers, inversion-of-control

I've always used C# interfaces to achieve inversion of control. But then I found this article which compares a bunch of IoC containers. What is the difference between these containers and a C# interface?

http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison

Comment: An [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) is like a contract for your code, and an IoC Container inverts the control of dependency management in an application. They can not be directly compared because they are not similar constructs.

Comment: It is like different types of libraries that do the same thing but in different way and provide different API, but core concept is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a false comparison. **Abstractions** are a prerequisite to apply **Dependency Injection** and to conform to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). If you are applying DI without the help of a container, you are practicing [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). Pure DI is a valid practice.

When an application grows, the use of containers can become very convenient, because they enable [Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) to wire object graphs. If you start using a DI container, you still need to use **Abstractions**.

To learn more on when and why you should use a DI container, read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) and [this](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2015/12/when-should-you-use-a-container/).

Comment: It looks like I've been practicing Pure DI. Thanks for the explanation and the article links.